# Remove items from an HTML collection based on another HTML collection

Tags: javascript, html, htmlcollection

I'm trying to crete 3 HTML collections containing all my links on a page, so I can attach 3 separate function to each categories of links.
My first HTML collection is "header links", the second is "footer links" and the third is "all other links". I need to attach link tracking functions and other elements as well.

Creating the first two collections is fairly easy as I can do document.getElementById('header'); and document.getElementById('footer'); and then this.getElementsByTagName('a');
However, getting the third collection of "all other links" is a bit more tricky. There isn't a clean div that contains just the "middle" of the page, and there are links outside the header and footer that are also difficult to single out.
I wish I could do something like allLinks = document.linnks, and then filter out of that all the links already present in the first and second HTML collections.

Any way to do that ? Ideally I would like to avoid loading more libraries and pure JS would be welcome

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn the node lists into arrays, then use `filter()` to pull out links that are already in one of the other lists:

```
var hdr = document.getElementById('header');
var hlinks = arrayOf(hdr.getElementsByTagName('a'));

var ftr = document.getElementById('footer');
var flinks = arrayOf(ftr.getElementsByTagName('a'));

var others = arrayOf(document.getElementsByTagName('a')).
filter(
  function(element) {
    return (hlinks.indexOf(element) < 0) && (flinks.indexOf(element) < 0);
  }
);

function arrayOf(nodelist)
{
  var result = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i < nodelist.length; ++i )
    result.push(nodelist.item(i));

  return result;
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/ikebh

If you need to support older browsers that lack `Array.prototype.filter()`, include the code from [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility) to implement it when needed.